# Working with shapefiles in Python

Tags: python, shapefile, qgis, pyshp

I am currently working on the problem of generating roads from Openstreetmap files. I use these Osm files to create a shapefile from all different road types with different roadway numbers, widths and so on.
Later on, I would also like to use digital orthophotos (DOP) to eliminate inconsistencies and errors in the Osm files.

In the appendix you can see an example image of a DOP (with corrected shadows) and a generated mask, in addition to the mask there is the generated shapefile (with the different information contained).

**So much for the introduction, now for the main question:**
In order to generate road markings on the generated roads it is first necessary to split shapefiles according to individual lanes. How is that possible in Python?

Many thanks and greetings

[image: attachment]

Comment: This question might fit better on https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ok, thanks...https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267232/working-with-shapefiles-in-python